# trying to populate listview from asynctask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

trying to populate a listview from async task... everything is working fine, i get my json response, building the map, but somehow nothing gets passed to onPostExecute and the listview remains empty after the dialog is dismissed... dont get any errors... anyone got a hint?

heres the code:

```
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import com.loopj.android.http.*;

public class Success extends ListActivity {

private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
JSONArray data = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_success);
    new processHomeStream().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.success, menu);
    return true;
}

class processHomeStream extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Success.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>... passing) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("url-to-my-api", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) { 

        try {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
            data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);
            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                // processing the son response
                }

                map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                result.add(map);                    
            }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println(result);
        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Success.this, result, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_TITLE},
                new int[] { R.id.title,});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        }


    }

}
```

thanks!

Comment: You "asynced" http call twice :-) use AsyncTask or AsyncHttpClient not both at the same time

Comment: Test whether you are getting error on try catch. May be you are getting exception (JSON exception) in try catch block so result is remaining null. give log.d in catch block

Comment: `Test whether you are getting error on try catch. May be you are getting exception (JSON exception) in try catch block so result is remaining null. give log.d in catch block –  Md. Monsur Hossain Tonmoy` hehe good one... Main problem is `client.get` is **NOT blocking call**